# How to find actual value that is throwing truncation Error from a source file in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am importing a data from a text file which has millions of data rows to a OLE DB destination table using SSIS. When importing, I am getting  "Text was truncated" error for one of the column.

Is there an easy and quick way to find the row that is causing the error?

When I debug it from my local machine, it SSIS error gave me a column name and a row number. But the row number seems to be incorrect.

I also tried to redirect the error to a table but it only provided column number and error code. Not the actual value.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

When I debug it from my local machine, it SSIS error gave me a column name and a row number. But the row number seems to be incorrect.

I also tried to redirect the error to a table but it only provided column number and error code. Not the actual value.

Comment: We can figure this out, but we need more info. What is the definition of the source file? Double click on the Flat File Connection manager and let's look at what the columns are defined as. Screenshots will help here. Then you need to compare that to the data in the file, are the lengths reasonable for the data domain? Phone Number will probably fit in 10 characters for the United States but formatting and such, maybe 20 or 30 makes sense. Addresses can be an easy 70 characters. Comments, better believe they'll be more than the default size of 255 or whatever it is.

Comment: If you don't know what the source lengths are, if the destination was already defined, then mirror those sizes. If that's not an option, then in the Flat File Connection Manager, in the Columns tab, try the Suggest Types button. Unless you know better, uncheck the Suggest Smallest integer/real data type boxes. After clicking OK, go back through the column definitions and look at what columns grew in length from your original inspection. Nothing got bigger, then re-run but increase the rows to analyze from 200 to something else. Or do proper data profiling - but that's a different question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.